# Affine transformation of square

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

> Consider the following figure (the length of the sides in the square is 1):
>
> [image]
>
> The unit square is transformed into the rectangle by using scaling and rotation.
>
> What is the transformation matrix for the transformation that moves the unit square to the rectangle depicted above? (Hint: $A=A_\theta \,*A_s$)

I'm stuck here. How am I supposed to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$$A_{\theta} = \left(\begin{array}{c} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{array}\right)$$
realize a rotation of $\theta$ in $\{e_1,e_2\}$ and
$$A_s = \left(\begin{array}{c} a & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{array}\right)$$ maps $e_1$ into $a\cdot e_1$ and $e_2$ into $b\cdot e_2$.

Then,
$$A=A_{\theta} \cdot A_s = \left(\begin{array}{c} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} a & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c} a\cos\theta & -b\sin\theta \\ a\sin\theta & b\cos\theta \end{array}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Take the standard basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$ for $\Bbb{R}^2$. First, you have to rotate it by an angle of $\theta=\frac{3\pi}{4}\text{rad}$ (why?). So, you're mapping $e_1$ into $v_1$ and $e_2$ into $v_2$.

Then, you have to map $v_1$ into $w_1=\sqrt{2} v_1$ and $v_2$ into $w_2=2\sqrt{2}v_2$ (why?). And then, you're done.

Ps.: the order that you do this is not important

**Edit:** There is another way to solve this, a way that "hides" those steps (but I really appreciate if you understand the first one, it's more constructive).

Think about where you're going to send each vector of the basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$. We're looking for a transformation $A$ that maps $(1,0)\mapsto(-2,2)$ and $(0,1)\mapsto(-1,-1)$, that is,
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{c} -2 & -1 \\ 2 & -1 \end{array}\right)$$
and we're done.

Comment: Don't you think that $\theta=\frac{3\pi}{4}$ is enough ?

Comment: Yes, of course! I'm sorry. Fixed.

Comment: How do I know that $\frac{3\pi}{4} rad$ is enough?

Comment: Think about "where $e_1$ comes from" and "where you're going to send it".